# How easy is it to sell on BrickLink as a non-dealer?

Tags: shopping, bricklink

I have been looking at a few of my old LEGO sets on BrickLink and they seem to sell for a lot ($500-$1000) - the information also suggests they actually are being sold periodically.

However, I've never sold on there before. I know that with most sites like that (Ebay, etc) it's really hard to sell without any reviews/feedback and particularly for expensive items.

Is this something which is even reasonable for me to even attempt to sell on BrickLink?

Comment: Anecdotally, yes, it's fine. Depending on the rarity of the set it may even be fairly easy. My experience quite some time ago was that it was easy - I'm not sure how many people looked at my complete lack of feedback and didn't buy from me, but I found a buyer within a couple of weeks. I suggest limiting yourself to insured post and trying to be responsive to questions.

Comment: @Móż it's a set that's pretty rare and valuable as best I can tell - 10030 is the number. Looking there I see it is actually selling, too.

Answer (score 5):

In general, it is considered best to first build up a reputation (i.e. feedback) by selling smaller items, before offering up rare and expensive items. When a new seller (low or zero feedback) offers up an expensive set, the following might happen:

1. Buyers will be afraid to purchase from you as offering expensive sets for sale by low feedback buyers is associated with scams.
2. You expose yourself to fraudulent buyers who are preying on new seller and try to pull a fast one (e.g. claiming something never arrived, or claiming something arrived damaged, or even returning something opened and replaced).

This is not to say that those things will always happen, but low feedback raises warning flags.

Of course, with proper research and careful shipping you can avoid all of this, and especially if you are competitively priced you might sell sooner rather than later.

Being perceived as a scammer, or being scammed yourself, is something that is unfortunately a regular phenomenon on any marketplace, be it Amazon, EBay, BrickLink or Craigslist.

So net, just be careful and do proper research on how to best cover yourself against potential scams. Selling LEGO can be a very exhilarating experience!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I don't really like the way Bricklink is set up for sellers and actually think eBay is much easier. On eBay, you are able to start selling right away but with Bricklink they require you to make a purchase first, Which I think is ridiculous. If anything I would probably suggest to use Bricklink to get an idea of the price and then go sell it on eBay. At least that's what I am doing. Hope this helps.